# Caculate all volume of objects in viewer- Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I want to calculate all volume of objects in viewer but this returns arrayVolume = [] and vol = 0. Where did I go wrong?

```
    $("#kl").click(function(){
viewer.model.getExternalIdMapping(data => kl(data));
function kl(data){
    var arrayVolume = [];
    var vol;
    for(var key in data){
        var dbId = data[key];
        viewer.getProperties(dbId, function(e){
            //console.log('Entire object response ',e);
            //console.log('Properties ',e.properties);
            var propertiesObj = e.properties;
            propertiesObj.forEach(obj => {
                if(obj.displayName === "Volume"){
                    var volume = obj.displayValue;
                    arrayVolume.push(volume);
                }
            });
        });
    }
    vol= arrayVolume.reduce(function(a,b){return a+ b;},0)
    alert('w: '+arrayVolume);
    alert('w: '+vol);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful about synchronous vs. asynchronous code. The `viewer.getProperties` method is asynchronous, meaning that the callback you provided might be called *later*. In your code snippet the two `alert` calls are most likely called *before* the `arrayVolume` and `vol` properties are populated with your callback function.

Also, note that when you need to retrieve properties from more than one dbID, there's a better method for that: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Model/#getbulkproperties-dbids-options-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback.